# Linq using Distinct() in C# Lambda Expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

```
SFC.OrderFormModifiedMonitoringRecords
   .SelectMany(q => q.TimeModify, w => w.DateModify)
   .Distinct()
   .OrderBy(t => t)
   .SelectMany(t => new { RowID = t.rowID, OFnum = t.OFNo });
```

It's Error did i missed something or is it Completely Coded The Wrong Way? After this i'm gonna use this on a **Foreach** method to gather up multiple data without the duplicates.

Comment: what is the error? where is the error?

Comment: It's in this Statement { SFC.OrderFormModifiedMonitoringRecords.SelectMany(q => q.TimeModify, w => w.DateModify) } it says try specifying the type of argument explicity i did specify it right? or did i miss something? :(

Comment: The error you are getting is suggesting that the compiler can't figure out what the return type of SelectMany is. Thus it asks you to be explicit. Ie, use Selectmany<TypeA,TypeB>(  ) . Doing this will not solve the problem, but you will get a clearer error message. If you want us to help you, you must tell us more about the types. What is the type of TimeModify and DateModify and what do you expect the data to look like after the SelectMany statement (before distinct)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The delegate you pass to [`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx) must return an `IEnumerable` and is for collapsing multiple collections into one. So yes, something's definitely wrong here. I think you've confused it with [`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx) which simply maps one collection to another.

Without knowing what your goal is, it's hard to know exactly how to fix it, but I'm guessing you want something like this:

```
SFC.OrderFormModifiedMonitoringRecords
   .OrderBy(t => t.DateModify)
   .ThenBy(t => t.TimeModify)
   .Select(t => new { RowID = t.rowID, OFnum = t.OFNo })
   .Distinct();
```

Or in query syntax:

```
(from t in SFC.OrderFormModifiedMonitoringRecords
 orderby t.DateModify, t.TimeModify
 select new { RowID = t.rowID, OFnum = t.OFNo })
.Distinct();
```

This will order the records by `DateModify` then by `TimeModify`, select two properties, `rowID` and `OFNo` and return only distinct pairs of values.

Comment: I believe that .OrderBy(...) should be last, preceded by .Distinct().

Comment: @maremp Then you wouldn't be able to order the results because the `Select` doesn't include the relevant properties.